# Ending external programs with Python

Tags: python, process, kill, abort

I'm writing a program that needs to be able to kill certain processes. The two lines I'm currently using work; however, the second line **os.system(task)** launches command prompt for a split second whilst it's ending a process. Are there any equivalent lines which do not launch command prompt?

Snippet :

```
task = 'taskkill /im ' + taskname + ' /f'
os.system(task)
```

This is in Windows 7 if you couldn't have guessed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `subprocess.check_call` instead of `os.system`.  This won't launch the process in a console window.

```
import subprocess
taskname = '...'
task = 'taskkill /im ' + taskname + ' /f'
subprocess.check_call(task, shell=True)
```

Comment: FYI `check_call` is just a wrapper around `call`, itself a wrapper around `Popen`