# Python: Kill (terminate) a process from command prompt using Python

Tags: python, user-interface, abort, kill-process, taskkill

I am not very familiar with the computer software terminology (my apologies).

- I designed a GUI in Python that suppose to execute and/or terminate a script when an appropriate button (on the GUI) is pressed.
- When I press a "Start" button (QPushButton) on the GUI, the following command executes the script *filename.dut* in the command prompt as follows:
  subprocess.call ('launcher.exe localhost filename.dut', shell=True).
- I want to be able to terminate the script in a similar way, i.e., to press a "Stop" button on the GUI that will write into the command prompt an appropriate command to terminate the script.
  I think I can find the solution in this thread: [Ending external programs with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026791/ending-external-programs-with-python). The suggested solution is:

  ```
  import subprocess        
  taskname = '...'        
  task = 'taskkill /im ' + taskname + ' /f'         
  subprocess.check_call(task, shell=True)
  ```
- My quastion is how can I obtain the *taskname* ?

Any suggestions or alternate solution would be very appreciated.

Comment: I've never used the `subprocess` module, but if you can get the process id, [psutils](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/) looks like it might help.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `subprocess`, you don't need to call any external utilities.
`subprocess.Popen` class provides `terminate` method.

In order to use it, you'll need to replace `subprocess.call(...)` with `subprocess.Popen(...)`, which returns a `Popen` instance. For example,

```
task = subprocess.Popen('launcher.exe localhost filename.dut', shell=True)
# some time later
task.terminate()
```

Note that, unlike `call`, plain `Popen` doesn't wait for process to complete.

Consult the manual for more details: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html